# What is the purpose of the "detail" property in tasks.json?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, properties

I have written a VS Code task to compile a simple C program. I removed the "detail" property and it still compiled. What does the property do?

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/cc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/build/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/cc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `detail` usually means some extra text in a QuickPick list, look at the **Terminal** > **Run Task** menu

Comment: "_and where does one find detailed explanation of all of the properties used by Visual Studio code? I'm aware of Intellisense list of properties but has no definitions, explanations, nor examples._" I removed this part of your post because you should generally only ask one question per question post. please also see [Where can I find schema files for VS Code's JSON files like launch.json and tasks.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73333047/11107541)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from a quick experiment, at least one thing it does is that it shows as description text underneath the label field in the selection menu that appears when using the `Tasks: Run Task` command.

Comment: Yes, I see the text underneath the first row. It seems just for notatin.