The VS Code launch.json behavior seems different than documented, won't use the args property
I'm trying to setup launch.json and launchSettings.json for a C# project in VS Code. The behavior that I am seeing when I debug the project is not what the following documentation indicates.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugger-settings#_args
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugger-settings#_environment-variables
According to this I should be able to use "env": { "name": "value" } to set runtime environment variables, and "args": [ "arg1", "arg2" ] to supply command line arguments in launch.json for the debug session. Neither of these result in environment variables nor args values being set.
I have successfully set environment variables using launchSettings.json profile, with an "environmentVariables" : { "name": "value" } property of the profile and associating the profile via the "launchSettingsProfile": "<profile name>" property in launch.json. The "commandLineArgs": [ "arg1", "arg2" ] property of the profile still does not set the args parameter though.
On top of that the IntelliSense doesn't think any of the documented args, env, nor lauchSettingsProfile are valid, showing a yellow squiggly under the attribute names.

What is the JSON schema definition for the dotnet launch config that IntelliSense is using? What can I do to get the debug session to pick up the command line args values?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/73333047/11107541

I found my problem. The <TargetFramework> in the .csproj was incorrectly set to <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>. After I set that properly, the args values are properly set at runtime.

EDIT - Confusion of launchSettings.json files
It appears that the real reason the debug actually picked up the args is because I tried to set the args from within Visual Studio, which crated a <project folder>\Properties\launchSettings.json. That file follows the patter of:
{
  "profiles": {
    "<project name>": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "-f C:\\Project\\Test-Files\\test1.csv"
    }
  }
}

For .Net projects this is the launchSettings.json you want to use.
